# How to implement (laravel echo/pusher) with Nuxt 3

Tags: push-notification, vuejs3, laravel-echo, nuxt3

I need to display real time notifications in my Nuxt 3 app.

Backend developer uses (Laravel Echo and pusher).
I'm looking for helper libraries but all results only support Nuxt 2.
Any help please..?

I tried to use the libraries that work with Nuxt 2 but it didn't work with Composition API in Nuxt 3

Thanks..

Comment: have read the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/broadcasting#client-side-installation ?

Comment: Hi @Jazuly ..
Thank you for reply, but im search for package support Nuxt 3 composition API..

Comment: you can create a plugin in plugins folder. define it as client side, then you can call it on your composition api, learn more about plugin here https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins

Comment: Well, I'll give it a try.. Regards..

Answer (score 3):

For setting 'ssr:false';

install the packages

```
npm i laravel-echo
npm i pusher-js
```

Create the laravel-echo.ts file in the /plugins directory (edit the connection data following your configuration)

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'
import Pusher from 'pusher-js'

declare global {
  interface Window {
    Pusher:any;
    Echo:any;
  }
}

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
  window.Pusher = Pusher
  window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'pusher_key',
    wsHost: 'host',
    wsPort: 6001,
    cluster: 'mt1',
    forceTLS: false
  })
})
```

In the nuxt.config.ts file add:

```
  plugins: [
    ...
    '~/plugins/laravel-echo'
  ],
```

In your .vue declare:

```
  window.Echo.channel(Your_Channel).listen('.your_queue', (e: Your_Interface) => {
    ...
  })
```

Answer (score 3):

I just got it to work with Pusher and Laravel-Echo. The only problem I had was that the default Echo authorizer assumes you're using axios, which would infer the api endpoint. This was fixed for Nuxt3 by overwriting the authorizer in my laravel-echo.js plugin. Now it uses my custom $api util that has the api base-url preconfigured.

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'
import Pusher from 'pusher-js'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
  window.Pusher = Pusher

  window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: [pusher-key],
    cluster: [pusher-cluster],
    forceTLS: true,
    authorizer: (channel, options) => {
      return {
        authorize: async (socketId, callback) => {
          try {
            const response = await $api('/broadcasting/auth', {
              method: "POST",
              body: {
                socket_id: socketId,
                channel_name: channel.name
            }})

            callback(null, response)
          } catch (error) {
            callback(error)
          }
        }
      };
    },
  })
})
```

Comment: You can return provider instead of define echo in global window: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins#providing-helpers